# Android: Activity is using old intent if launching app from Recent Task

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, flags

I'm implementing GCM. My app has two activities, say `A` and `B`. I'm using this code to launch `B` from the NotificationBar:

```
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager notificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);        
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.app_notification_icon, "De Centrale", when);//message
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, B.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); //|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, msg, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

NotificationBar opens Activity `B` with an Intent, say 'B-notification-intent', then I open Activity `A` from `B` using Back button, then again I launch `B` from `A` having a new Intent (say 'B-A-intent'). I use the code below:

```
intent = new Intent(this, B.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);              
startActivity(intent);
```

And then I get New Data in `B` (i.e the screen of `B` is refreshed).
But if I press the Home button and then I launch the application from Recent app then I get older `B` screen with 'B-notification-intent'. Instead, I want the latest Intent, i.e 'B-A-intent'. I'm using this code in `B`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    fetchDataFromDB(getIntent());           
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    fetchDataFromDB(intent);        
}
```

So anybody please help me getting my current screen (intent).

Comment: try changing it to on resume 
protected void onResume(Bundle b)
        {
        fetchDataFromDB(getIntent());

            }

Comment: @droidhot Please explain your answer(What I was doing wrong) and post it below in answer block

Comment: when you press the home button the activity goes to on pause state and when it comes back on resume is called and on start is not called as such the data will be of the intent at the time of on create which in your case is the notification intent referr activity life cycle to understand it better

Comment: @droidhot But your solution is causing one more problem.If my actity B is already open then after getting push,screen is not being refreshed because does onResume is holding the old intent so how to refresh new intent?

Comment: after you click on the notification is it not refreshing?? its not the problem with on resume anyway (please check activity life cycle) you can create a function or a reciver to solve the problem -- ( i hope if you click on the notification its showing the refreshed screen)-- if you note the facebook app it will not refresh the curent screen with new pushs but you ll have to pull to refresh--

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I also noticed that sometimes an `Activity`'s `onCreate()` was getting stale `Intent`s when launched from Recents, but there *is* a way to check for that so you can handle the `Intent` appropriately.

JAVA:

```
protected boolean wasLaunchedFromRecents() {
    return (getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun wasLaunchedFromRecents(): Boolean {
    val flags: Int = intent.flags and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY
    return flags == Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY
}
```

In my humble opinion, that flag is poorly named (other flags referencing the Recents list actually use that word, e.g. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS`) and the documentation was never updated to reflect the fact that many popular Android devices have a dedicated button for Recents:

> This flag is not normally set by application code, but set for you by the system if this activity is being launched from history (longpress home key).

(N.B. I realize that you solved your issue another way years ago, but this question is one of the top search results for 'android old intent recent' and none of the other related questions mention this flag, so hopefully this Answer can help someone else.)

Comment: This is very helpful when launcher activity also received intent.

Comment: I wasted half of my day for this. Much useful.

Comment: Damn, I was looking for 336592896 for two days what is this intent flag. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! FYI we are using the JAVA `&` bitwise operator here. I have edited the answer to add Kotlin version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason [bkDJ's / the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29489276/14745399) did not work for me. Only if the accepted answer also does not work for you, try this:

Neither FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY, nor setting a boolean to the intent after it was handled the first time prevented the intent from being being reused.

I had to add a timestamp to each intent where this issue occured. And only execute the intent if the timestamp was not older than 30 seconds.

Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT, TargetActivity.class);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
intent.putExtra("timestampOfIntentInMilliseconds", now.getTimeInMillis());
// put your actual extras to the intent
```

then when handling the intent:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
long timestampOfIntentInMilliseconds = extras.getLong("timestampOfIntentInMilliseconds");
now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.getTimeInMillis() < (timestampOfIntentInMilliseconds + 30000))
{
   // do what you want to do with the intent
}
```