# Android Intent survives through app relaunch / Airbnb deep link survives through app relaunch

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

We used this Airbnb deep link dispatch lib in our app.
https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch

Below is the issue app is facing.

1. Kill app.
2. Launch app with deep link. That opened, say, a dialog on top of activity.
3. press back key on app and close it.
4. Launch it again through Recent Tasks.
   Dialog shows up again. Repeat steps, it shows up again.
   This is mostly because on back key, process is not dead and activity has overrides onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). I see in onCreate() that getIntent() returns the intent with same previous deep link. Hence the problem.
   This does not happen if I launch app from home screen in which case it posts the launch home intent so the previous intent could have been replaced with it and so gone.

I know it is how it works in Android. But is there a way in this lib or in Android to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

It was not an issue with Airbnb library but that is how it works with Android. When launched from recents after killing app with **back key**, Android posts the previous intent that was used to launch app.
[Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS) indicates if app launched from history/recent screen. This flag can be used to handle any logic.

Credits to [Android: Activity is using old intent if launching app from Recent Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135545/android-activity-is-using-old-intent-if-launching-app-from-recent-task)